# Script error: "Unable to get value of the property 'split': Object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript

I searched around, and couldn't find an answer to my question. I'm very new at coding, and at work, we have an application that current names that are logged in, and what they are doing.

Recently, they have changed from jquery 1.4.1 to jquery 1.8.3. Ever since then, I cannot get the results to process correctly, because of the following error;
"Unable to get value of the property 'split': Object is null or undefined"

I have the code setup to grab the results and split them;

```
function processAgents(xData, status) {
var avail    = xData.responseText.split("|")[0];
var acw      = xData.responseText.split("|")[1];
var total    = xData.responseText.split("|")[2];
var breaks    = xData.responseText.split("|")[3];
var pending  = xData.responseText.split("|")[4];
```

The application is setup to open as an HTA file which opens up the PHP script.

Any help would be appreciated, please let me know if I left anything out!

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

I did some more investigating, and it looks like I'm not getting data from my process request. This is how it is currently setup

```
function updateAgents() {
var ts1 = new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({
      url: "http://SERVER/AgentSrc.php?x=" + ts1,
      complete: processAgents
```

I'm not sure if this is processing correctly since they went to jquery 1.8.3.

**EDIT 2**
So after looking into it more, it doesn't appear that the script is getting the data from the server, even though I have access. If I make a local file and put the information in it, it will pull the information and split it, but if I point to the path of the file on the server, it won't get the information. But the strange thing is, if I run it using jquery 1.4.1, it pulls the data fine, but can't display it. But with 1.8.3, it doesn't allow me to pull it from the server.

thanks again!

Comment: Are you sure it is due to jquery updgrade? Split has nothing to do with jquery it is native javascript string method.

Comment: I thought it was. When I keep the jquery 1.4.1 on the code, it will split the names vertically, instead of horizontally like it used too. But when using the 1.8.3, I receive that error. I suppose that it could be something else.

Comment: The error means xData.responseText is null or undefined. Where is xData coming from?

Comment: 1. Are you sure xData.responseText is not undefined, 2. inside your processAgents just place `alert("".split);` and see if it shows the function reference.

Comment: @bfavaretto To be honest, I'm not sure. I'm still learning all that stuff. Where would I look for that?

Comment: @PSL Comes up saying "Native Code"

Comment: Ok. It had to. Did you try :Hogan's answer. How about xData.responseText?

Comment: Look for the part that calls that function. I believe Christophe is right, you're probably passing the return value of a jQuery Ajax call.

Comment: I tried 
'alert(""xData.responseText);'
and received "Error expected ')'"

Comment: alert(xData.responseText); also alert (xData)

Comment: @bfavaretto No, when just using 'alert(xData.responseText);' it says undefined

Comment: alert(xData) shows [object Object]

Comment: Again, find the call to processAgents, the problem should be nearby.

Comment: SO that says it you are trying to split undefined, but error message for this is weird though. whats in your xData, . do console.log(JSON.stringify(xData))

Comment: @PSL where do I put that at? And will it work right, opening it as an HTA? Thanks for everyones help so far.

Comment: @PSL Alerting xData results in [object Object]

Comment: i mean alert(JSON.stringify(xData))

Comment: @PSL Pulling that up in HTA says JSON undefined. But in firebug, it says 
'"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"'

Answer (score 1):

This will give some clarity

```
xData.responseText.toString().split("|")[0];
```

(split is part of string not jQuery)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "give some clarity" Should I replace 
xData.responseText.split("|")[0];
to
xData.responseText.toString().split("|")[0];

Comment: Thanks for the response. It says "Unable to get value of the property 'toStrink': object is null or undefined"

Comment: @gokou340 - you have a k... it is `toString()` not `toStrink`

Comment: sorry, that was a mistype, I actually had it as toString

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible explanation: in earlier versions of jQuery, ajax calls returned an xmlHttpRequest (XHR) object. Recent versions return a promise (jqXHR) instead.

[See this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.